# Pulling text value from <a class> <b class> with Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping

I'm using selenium to draw some information about ownership for a given PredictIt market (ie, https://www.predictit.org/Home/SingleOption?contractId=7347#data).  The shares owned is nested in:
[image]
How can I pull out the number?

I've tried

```
self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("showpointer showOwnership").text

self.driver.find_element_by_id('showpointer showOwnership')

self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("label alert-success label-lg")

self.find_element_by_css_selector("spand[class='label alert-success label-lg']")

self.driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#ctrlNotesWindow .notesData > .notesDate")).getText())
```

all to no avail.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Edit: All errors have been:
"NoSuchElement Error"

Comment: Try [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why your attempts failed:**

- the "by class name" locators requires you to specify a single class name - not multiple of them
- there are no `id` elements present - the "by id" locator would match nothing
- you are looking for a non-existent `spand` element with your CSS selector. Plus, you are calling `find_element_by_css_selector` on `self` instead of `self.driver`
- your last attempt is in Java, not in Python

Judging by what you've posted, I would use a CSS selector checking classes of `a` and `b`:

```
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.showOwnership > b.label").text
```

Comment: Thanks. That produces selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="[alphanumeric]", element="[alphanumeric]")

Comment: @libertyspursuit sure, just get the `.text` attribute value (updated the code in the answer as well).

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you so much for the explanations and code help!